# Unable to load pgirmess library ("image not found") - R 3.4 in Mac OS

Tags: r

Just moved on to new computer (Mac OS Sierra), and fail to load the pgirmess package after installing it. Installation of the package completes, however, library(pgirmess) gives:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘pgirmess’ in 
dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object 
'/Users/nilsson/Library/R/3.4/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so':
  dlopen(/Users/nilsson/Library/R/3.4/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so, 6): 
Library not loaded: /Builds/unix/recipes/build/gdal-2.1.3-
obj/libgdal.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/nilsson/Library/R/3.4/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I have installed XQuartz. I did try to install the package they are asking for but it did not solve the problem (same error message as above when i load rgdal). Other packages work so far. All packages were installed with install.packages(). Thankful for any suggestions.

Update: Installed previous version of R (3.3.3) and it works. Will stick to that until solution appears.

Comment: Have you installed and can you load the `rgdal` package? If not, what exact errors do you get there? Did you install these via `install.packages`?

Comment: Everything with install.packages, yes. I installed rgdal, loading the library gives the same error as above.

Comment: And `rgdal` installed without error? Try uninstalling it and re-installing it. I'd be curious if there were any errors or warnings during install.

Comment: Neither installing rgdal nor pgirmess gives any warnings at this point. I don't remember if it did the first time (now I just removed packages and installed again, no warnings).